# Julia storing a batch of sparse matrices and multiplying them to a vector

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I store N matrices, each of size(n,n), in the array Batchm = zeros(ComplexF64, N,n,n ). Later, I retrieve the individual matrices and multiply to a vector, Batchm(index, :,:)*v.
The matrices are sparse and banded. What's the best way to store them as sparse matrices in a structure (like Batchm), for subsequent retrieval and multiplication?